# Sort subfolders and filenames of a directory numerically using boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-filesystem

I am using the same example as in the boost [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/example/tut4.cpp). But since my file names are numbered (1,20,23,..). The code fails to compare the strings(ex. 20 < 7). Is there a way to compare the directory_iteration numerically. Here is a snippet of the code

```
else if (is_directory(p))      // is p a directory?
      {
        cout << p << " is a directory containing:\n";

        typedef vector<path> vec;             // store paths,
        vec v;                                // so we can sort them later

        copy(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), back_inserter(v));

        sort(v.begin(), v.end());             //  **I want to sort this numerically**

        for (vec::const_iterator it(v.begin()), it_end(v.end()); it != it_end; ++it)
        {
          cout << "   " << *it << '\n';
        }
      }
```

The layout of Directory and subfolder is shown here:

```
root/
    1/
     1.bmp
     2.bmp
     3.bmp
     4.bmp
     ...
    2/
     1.bmp
     2.bmp
     3.bmp
     4.bmp
    ....
    3/
     1.bmp
     2.bmp
     3.bmp
     4.bmp
     ....
```

Comment: Next time use a fixed number of digits (to accomodate all the values used) with 0-padding in your file names, and the problem will go away. e.g when we expect at most 100 files (0-99) name the files like `01.txt`, `20.txt`, `23.txt`, etc. | Right now you'll have to parse the numerical value of the the filename and use that to sort by.

Comment: @DanMašek The files are automatically generated by another software, I am not sure I can edit that  since it's a commercial software. I have to work with what I have. I have more than 50 subfolders each with files numbered from 1:127, it would tidus to rename them by myself. Thnx

Comment: Use a custom comparator that gets these numbers from the paths and compares them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot change the format of the filenames to be sortable as is, you will need to do some processing yourself -- parse the number from each file name, and use that for sorting.

Two approaches come to mind, trading off between memory and CPU usage.

Approach 1:

Store pairs of filename and numerical value, parsing when populating the vector.

Approach 2:

Store just the paths and perform conversion during comparison.

---

Code:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int parse_filename(fs::path const& p)
{
    return std::stoi(p.filename().string());
}

void sort_numeric_1(fs::path const& p)
{
    typedef std::pair<fs::path, int> file_entry;
    typedef std::vector<file_entry> vec;
    vec v;

    for (fs::directory_iterator it(p); it != fs::directory_iterator(); ++it) {
        v.emplace_back(*it, parse_filename(*it));
    }

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()
        , [](file_entry const& a, file_entry const& b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    });

    for (vec::const_iterator it(v.begin()), it_end(v.end()); it != it_end; ++it) {
        std::cout << "   " << it->first << '\n';
    }
}

void sort_numeric_2(fs::path const& p)
{
    typedef std::vector<fs::path> vec;
    vec v;

    std::copy(fs::directory_iterator(p), fs::directory_iterator(), back_inserter(v));

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()
        , [](fs::path const& a, fs::path const& b) {
        return std::stoi(a.filename().string()) < std::stoi(b.filename().string());
    });

    for (vec::const_iterator it(v.begin()), it_end(v.end()); it != it_end; ++it) {
        std::cout << "   " << *it << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    sort_numeric_1("test");
    std::cout <<"\n";
    sort_numeric_2("test");
}
```

Contents of the directory:

```
> ls test
1.txt  10.txt  127.txt  20.txt  23.txt
```

Output:

```
"test\1.txt"
"test\10.txt"
"test\20.txt"
"test\23.txt"
"test\127.txt"

"test\1.txt"
"test\10.txt"
"test\20.txt"
"test\23.txt"
"test\127.txt"
```

---

Updating it to handle the whole directory structure you've shown, you could have something like this:

- first find all the directories, and sort them numerically
- then sort files in each of the found directories
- merge all the sorted lists of files

Example:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

typedef std::vector<fs::path> path_vec;

void sort_numeric(path_vec& v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()
        , [](fs::path const& a, fs::path const& b) {
        return std::stoi(a.filename().string()) < std::stoi(b.filename().string());
    });
}

path_vec sort_root_dir(fs::path const& p)
{
    path_vec dirs;

    for (fs::directory_iterator it(p); it != fs::directory_iterator(); ++it) {
        if (is_directory(*it)) {
            dirs.emplace_back(*it);
        }
    }

    sort_numeric(dirs);

    path_vec files;
    for (path_vec::const_iterator it(dirs.begin()), it_end(dirs.end()); it != it_end; ++it) {
        path_vec dir_files;
        std::copy(fs::directory_iterator(*it), fs::directory_iterator(), back_inserter(dir_files));
        sort_numeric(dir_files);
        files.insert(files.end(), dir_files.begin(), dir_files.end());
    }

    return files;
}

int main()
{
    path_vec files = sort_root_dir("test");

    for (auto const& f : files) {
        std::cout << f << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfect if I  only have one subfolder, for multiple subfolders it fails and gives me (terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what():  stoi).

Comment: This is just a basic example on how to do the sorting for a single directory with just files. You will have to add some extra checks to handle nested directories. Perhaps if you can show us some example of the layout of directory tree (so we know what to expect), you can have more complete solution.